# Best icon for linking to a different page on the same website?

Tags: icons, hyperlinks

Below is the current icon I'm using (top right of boxes). I'm worried that it looks like an external link.

[image]

Is there a standard icon used for internal links? I was thinking about something similar to [this](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/link?style=solid) but I'm not sure if it's any better.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, looks more like a "get permalink" icon. Maybe having no icon would be enough of a contrast with the external one, and people can learn clickability the normal way. (In fact, if there are a lot of cards with similar structure differing only by the icon, I probably will find it very hard to accurately distinguish the icons as I scroll.) Also, given the nature of these links, is it actually essential that the user sees one as being part of the site and the other not? In terms of UX the descriptions both sound like they will feel like different sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it looks like an external link icon, that if you click it you will leave the site. For internal navigation I usually just use a regular arrow. https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=Arrow%20right&c=arrows